# debugging node 8 with visual studio code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Using Visual Studio Code Version 1.13.0, when started a node debug test2.js, the node is version 0.12 with following config, I can debug and response from vscode was:

```
Debugging with legacy protocol because it was detected.
```

but when the node is V8.0 and 'node debug test2.js' is issued, debugging VSCODE got:

```
Debugging with legacy protocol because Node.js version could not be determined (Error: read ECONNRESET)
```

Any idea why? I'm using 'attach', the config as follow:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
  {
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach",
    "port": 5858
  }
  {
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Program",
    "program": "${file}"
  }
]
```

Comment: using this works: node --inspect-brk=172.17.0.2:5858 test2.js

Comment: I solved it by upgrading to latest VScode version...
https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the new "inspector" protocol as the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging) says:

```
 {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach (Inspector Protocol)",
        "port": 9229,
        "protocol": "inspector"
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

If you still get the error:
***debugging with legacy protocol because node.js version could not be determined***

Use the following steps:

1. brew uninstall node.
2. restar computer.
3. brew install node.

It works in Visual Studio Code Version 1.15.1; node Version 8.4.0